# Is "the" possible as a right answer? (English test from Japanese year 7)

Tags: difference, articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

> This box is big. This (  )(  )(  ) box.
>   *Fill in the blanks so those two sentences can be almost the same meaning.*

I know the answer is This (is)(a)(big) box.
However many children use "the" instead of "a" and I can't tell them a reason.
Could "the" be an another right answer?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could deliberately construct a context where the version with the definite article works:

> There are two boxes in the room. This box (pointing to one) is big. This is the big box.

However, I would advise against making up more context to fit with an otherwise incorrect answer. Since in your title you specify the test as from a textbook for Japanese kids age 7 (first graders? 小一年生？), it is important that they learn the proper function of articles and the difference between the definite and indefinite articles, which I believe is also the intention behind this quiz question.

For people whose native language doesn't have the concept of article, it is especially difficult to learn and master the correct use of articles in English. Japanese speakers especially tend to overuse the definite article "the". So I would recommend explaining to the students why they should use the indefinite article "a" here instead of the definite article in the original test question:

A big box is a generic object. There are more than one big box. Without previously specifying which big box we are talking about, the definite article doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you so much Eddie san.

Comment: @Jessy If I have answered the question to your satisfaction, please consider accepting my answer. :)